# How to detect from which button a form is submitted from a loop

Tags: php, sql

I made a loop that creates multiple divs. In the divs you can find a form for submitting something.
I now want to detect from which button a form has been submitted. How can I do this?

```
<?php 
      if(!empty($aw)){
      $element = "<div class='agendadiv'>
                    <h2>WEEK</h2>
                    <form method='post'>
                      <label for='oefs'>Welke oefeningen zijn er gepland voor deze week?</label></br>
                      <input type='text' name='oefs'>
                      <button id='oefsklaar' type='submit' name='oef'>Voeg Toe</button>                            
                    </form>
                  </div>";
      $count = $aw;
        foreach( range(1,$count) as $item){
            echo $element;
        }
      }else{
        ?> <h2>Maak een agenda aan aub.</h2> <?php
      }

?>
```

The `$aw` variable holds the numbers of divs that have to be created. I get this value from the database.

The code works but I want to be able to detect from which button a form has been submitted so I can add that in the database for when I want to show the submitted value I can show the value/div.

Otherwise you can see the entered value in div 1 in all divs. I only want to be able to see the value entered in div 1 in div1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make unique your submit button name like:-

```
<?php 
      if(!empty($aw)){
      $count = $aw;
      $i=1;
        foreach( range(1,$count) as $item){
            $element = "<div class='agendadiv'>
                    <h2>WEEK</h2>
                    <form method='post'>
                      <label for='oefs'>Welke oefeningen zijn er gepland voor deze week?</label></br>
                      <input type='text' name='oefs'>
                      <button id='oefsklaar' type='submit' name='oef$i'>Voeg Toe</button>                            
                    </form>
                  </div>";
            echo $element;
            $i++;
        }
      }else{
        ?> <h2>Maak een agenda aan aub.</h2> <?php
      }
?>
```

I have added a counter that added to button name you can also use for form name
you can check like : `$_POST['oef1']` is set and so on

For add more with element:-

```
$element = "<div class='agendadiv'>
                    <h2>WEEK</h2>
                    <form method='post'>
                      <label for='oefs'>Welke oefeningen zijn er gepland voor deze week?</label></br>
                      <input type='text' name='oefs'>
                      <button id='oefsklaar' type='submit' name='oef$i'>Voeg Toe</button>";
            if (!empty($alloefs)) { 
                foreach($alloefs as $a) { 
                  $element .="<ul> <li>".$a['oefening']."</li> </br> </ul>";
                   } }                           
                 $element .=  "</form>
                  </div>";
```

Comment: ...and in your form processing code, check if `$_POST['oef1']` exists to know if the first form got submitted

Comment: One more thing how can I write php in that $element? I want to add this under the button <http://puu.sh/8SvZr.png

Comment: updating answer please check

Comment: hello with your code if I add something I get the results in all the divs can I get the results of the button in the div that has been submitted from? example I submit from div 1 button 1 I only want to see the results in div 1, if I submitted from div 2 button 2 I want to see those results in div 2